# Is there a way to detect column data type with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that these details are on the information schema, but my table contains all columns in the form of varchar(max) since they are directly written from a flat file source. I want to detect the column type based on the values in the columns. I'm not able to control how the data comes in, so this table is my source.

So for example if Column1 has values like {1, 2, 100, 'NA', NULL, 'Not available', 'Not provided by vendor'}, my current SQL statement classifies this column as varchar. I want to be able to assign an INT to this column, dynamically. We can safely assume that the number of integers coming in will be greater than the other type of fields in the column.

Comment: Do you mean broadly speaking numeric or not? you can use `ISNUMERIC` or `TRY_CAST`

Comment: Why would you have all varchar(max) when you read from a flat file source? What does it mean to detect the columns type from the values on the column? Doesn't a  flat file importer already does that? (but you have used all varchar(max)). Maybe you should use an intermediate flat file reader in between. Nobody would really do a "blind" reading but if you do maybe you should consider using something like ACE.OleDbDriver. It could return you the data with types (at least better than all varchar(max). That "flat file" might be easily read with say Linq To CSV too.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm using SSIS and no the flat file reader does not auto detect in most cases. The number of columns is not fixed and usually there are 300+ columns. I could do some intermediate FF interpreter, but I'm looking for an easy to implement solution with just SQL.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid a broad classification like that works, but what if I have just one string in an otherwise integer column?. Is there a way to assign data types based on the data type of majority of values in the column?

Comment: If you were to load this into a table with proper data types and you wanted to define a column as integer and it had a string value in it then you'd need to either not load the record or set it's value to something like NULL. You're defining the rules here.

Comment: I assume this data eventually arrives in a properly modeled table with defined data types. So you eventually have to do some column mapping. So dynamically defining data types doesn't help here

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The destination has not been modeled yet, Basically I want the destination table to be built from the metadata. So I want the flow to be something like this -- source table -> detect column types -> store metadata -> generate destination table from metadata -> transfer data. Since there are a huge number of columns coming in, it's practically not possible for me to design a destination each time the source changes.

Comment: Saying "flat file reader" I didn't mean MS SQL Server itself. With MS SQL I itself I don't have much hope, at least I couldn't use MS SQL for flat file reading, always used intermediate solutions.

Comment: Saying columns, how do you differentiate columns?

Comment: What if it was always [0-9]+ and then became "NONE"? You do know flat file content, you do have an exchange protocol, data format contract or you don't. You may have assumptions but they may break this ETL someday.

Comment: Yes you could just count the designated data type and come up with a proposed data type but you certainly couldn't load the data anywhere until you sorted it out.

Comment: You still need to write the inspection SQL individually for each column.... you could also make that dynamic of course. Sample inspection SQL for just one column could be `SELECT SUM(IIF(TRY_CAST(YourColumn AS INT) IS NULL,0,1)) As ImNumeric, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable`. If you post some sample schema I could have a crack though I'm not really into writing peoples code for them.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes I wrote something along the same line, and it works for now. I used ISNUMERIC and ISDATE functions, and assigned data types using the max group by value. It works well for now. Thanks!

Comment: Read this before you use ISNUMERIC https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manub22/2013/12/23/use-new-try_parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your column contains data like 'NA',  'Not available', 'Not provided by vendor' then it can not be a numeric, you have to clean your data first then change the data type accordingly

for numeric data you can check using ISNUMERIC function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

for date  data you can check using ISDATE function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing for this built into Sql Server. Like other databases, Sql Server expects you to use column types other than `varchar(max)` for everything. If you're data is in flat files, you inspect the files **before** import to know what it is exactly you are importing and set that as part of the SSIS job or other import process.

Comment: There are definitely cases where it's easier to import data into varchar(max) columns then use SQL to parse it into the proper datatypes. For example to import ragged right type files